# How can I assign pre value boost/weight to a document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to know if there is a way to assign a pre value boost or weight to some documents like I can do for the complete suggestions.

Lets say I index two documents:

```
Gerogia
Germany
```

For an autocomplete search I will type `Ger` and receive both of the documents. Both of the documents have the same score. But I would like to assign a weight or a higher ranking on document `Germany` because this is a country. This I know while indexing.

With the complete suggester I can do that:

```
{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Germany" ],
        "weight" : 50
    }
}

{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Georgia" ],
        "weight" : 25
    }
}
```

But I dont want to use the complete suggester functions.

So is there a way to pre boost or pre rank documents while indexing?